# Check data from multiple tables and get result from correct table

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, left-join

I have a database with these tables

```
Access (UID, Username, Password, Role)
Admission_Students (UID, Name, ETC)
Admission_Lecturers (UID, Name, ETC)
Admission_Admins (UID, Name, ETC)
```

I want to write a query that checks if entered username and password exists in `Access` table and then get `Name` and other information from the relevant `Admission_*` table based on `Role` from `Access` table or `UID`.

I tried `SELECT` and joins but I couldn't put it together. I need an efficient query for my VB.NET app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use three left joins:

```
select
  a.*,
  coalesce(s.name, l.name, d.name) as name,
  coalesce(s.etc, l.etc, d.etc) as etc
from access a
left join admission_students s on s.uid = a.uid and a.role = 'student'
left join admission_leturers l on l.uid = a.uid and a.role = 'lecturer'
left join admission_admins d on d.uid = a.uid and a.role = 'admin'
where username = 'conanthebarbarian'
```